# Looking for a contemporary device similar to what the Yoggie used to be

Tags: usb, firewall

About ten years back there was a range of products all called [Yoggie](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/ces-usb-security,news-256.html). Some of them were bigger, some of them looked like bulky USB sticks (i.e. too wide to fit other USB plugs next to them), called Yoggie Pico.

On them was - as far as I know - a XScale-based Linux system which was running netfilter (or perhaps its predecessor, I don't remember). It used a method similar to [PoisonTap](https://samy.pl/poisontap/) to pose as USB-Ethernet device to the host system and (ab)use the fact that DHCP was enabled to push default routes to itself and thereby being a firewall on a system logically separate from the host.

Is anyone aware of a USB device - preferably even tinier than the original Yoggies - that could perform a similar task at contemporary higher throughput rates (both USB and Ethernet)? Price should preferably be below 200 USD.

Comment: I'm curious, what are you planning to do with the device? It sounds like a very interesting project :)

Answer (score 0):

One device I found which allows this and is considerably cheaper than the Yoggies were is the [Microuter](https://openwrt.org/toh/gl.inet/gl.inet_gl-usb150) (formal model name [GL.iNet GL-USB150](https://www.gl-inet.com/products/gl-usb150/)).

It is somewhat bigger than the Yoggie Pico (mostly longer), but given it runs OpenWRT (albeit customized) it is somewhat more accessible than the Yoggies were at the time.